# Topology Exception

Tags: postgis, postgresql

With this query:

```
select sa1."Code", ut1."Name",  max(r1."Version"), (select st_distance(st_makevalid(center)::geography,st_makevalid(nearest)::geography) from st_maximuminscribedcircle(st_makevalid(st_union(st_makevalid(rp1."Geometry"))))) as distance
        from "table1" sa1
            join "table2" saut on sa1."ID" = saut."ServiceAreaID"
            join "table3" ut1 on saut."UID" = ut1."ID"
            join "table4" r1 on sa1."ID" = r1."SID"
            join "table5" rp1 on r1."ID" = rp1."RID"
        group by 1,2
```

I get this error:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: lwgeom_unaryunion_prec: GEOS Error: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (-79.0231 33.6278, -79.0231 33.6278) and LINESTRING (-79.0231 33.6278, -79.0231 33.6278) at -79.023128146474221 33.627840125152325
  ERROR: lwgeom_unaryunion_prec: GEOS Error: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (-79.0231 33.6278, -79.0231 33.6278) and LINESTRING (-79.0231 33.6278, -79.0231 33.6278) at -79.023128146474221 33.627840125152325
  ERROR: lwgeom_unaryunion_prec: GEOS Error: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (-79.0231 33.6278, -79.0231 33.6278) and LINESTRING (-79.0231 33.6278, -79.0231 33.6278) at -79.023128146474221 33.627840125152325
```

In the past if I wrapped the geom in `makevalid` (as I did here) it would solve the problem. Are there any trouble shooting tips or solutions that come to mind?

Comment: What version of PostGIS and GEOS?  TopologyExceptions are essentially eliminated in GEOS 3.9+

Comment: PostGIS 3.2.1 GEOS 3.1

Comment: CORRECTION: PostGIS 3.1.4 GEOS 3.9 I also realized that its not just on insert, DBeaver was truncating the select query so it was making it seem as if it was working correctly. I'm updating the question now

Comment: It would be helpful if you can isolate and post the geometry causing the problem.

Comment: If the input geometries are already valid, then `ST_MakeValid` is not needed.

Comment: You might be able to use `ST_Buffer(ST_Collect(rp1.geom), 0)` instead of `ST_Union`.

Comment: @dr_jts I saw the other posts that suggest truncating the accuracy of the coordinates so I tried this and it worked: `st_union(st_makevalid(rp1."Geometry"),0.00000001)))`